# Massively multi-tenant programmable CMS?

Tags: .net, content-management-system

I have the need for a massively multi-tenant CMS that allows customizability per site and per user.

Think something like Myspace, where it's generally a single template tied to a profile of some sort, but allows the user to customize that template however they want.

BY "massively" I mean on the realm of 100,000+ "sites", Many will have their own domain, many will be subdomains of a parent domain.

The scale of the multi-tenancy makes most systems impractical because they require custom configuration of each site.

Perhaps what i'm really looking for is some kind of CMS "toolkit" that will allow me to build what I want, but gives me the tools to do so.

I would prefer something .NET oriented, but anything will work.

Does anyone have any pointers on projects or systems to look into?

Comment: Can't think of one offhand, but I'd love to actually *write* one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

DOTNETNUKE. You will be able to thousands of sites off the same code base. Has a bit of a learning curve to develop "modules" for it, but what CMS doesn't.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with DNN, and it really doesn't fit the bill.  As I said, I don't want to have to custom configure each site.  Further, DNN's customization is not conducive to allowing non-priviledge end-users to do it.